# Is $\log(\log(n)) = \Theta(\log(n))$? Reasoning with words

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics

I am looking for confirmation of my reasoning. I believe $\log(\log(n)) = \Theta(\log(n))$ simply because we can treat the inner $\log(n)$ of the $\log(\log(n))$ as a variable that grows towards infinity. To me, it does not matter that we nest these $\log()$ functions because at the end of the day, the inner $\log(n)$ of $\log(\log(n))$ will grow and act as if it were just a slowly increasing value as we plug larger and larger numbers into it.

But this might be a flawed attempt to reason with words, so any clarification or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is $\log(n)\in\Theta(n)$? That same logic works; after all, both are going to infinity...

Comment: No, if $$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log(n)}{\log(\log(n))}<\infty$$ were true, we would have, using the substitution $x=\log(n)$, $$\limsup_{x\to\infty} \frac{x}{\log(x)}=\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log(n)}{\log(\log(n))}<\infty$$ which cannot be true because $x$ grows too fast in comparison to $\log(x)$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: I understand my error in thinking. Thanks guys.

Comment: You want to treat the inner $\log n$ in $\log\log n$ as a variable. OK, let's call that variable $x$. So $x=\log n$. In terms of the new variable $x$, your question is whether $\log x=\Theta(x)$. And that brings us back to @StevenStadnicki's comment.